# How to anchor audio or video in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm just a beginner.. How to play a video or audio using the anchor tag?
I used the  tag n it played normally... I used the  n it played... But when I anchor it:

```
<html>
<a href ="D:\Owl City\Owl City - All Things Bright and Beautiful [iTumrd Bonus Track Version]-AAC-(2011)\13 Alligator Sky (No Rap Version).m4a"> Click here! </a>
</html>
```

It launched WMP or VLC... Is it possible to play it without launching other applications?

Comment: HTML5 introduces the [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/audio) element, that could be one option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML5 tags, like [video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) or [audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) . It's fairly easy to customize. See [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop).

Be aware that old browsers don't support HTML5 and that you need different versions of the files for a couple of browsers. It's all explained on the linked sites.

What you are doing now is using the a tag to link a file. This will not embed the content in your website, but opens a player on your computer.